# How can I change the standard audio output device?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I use the pulseaudio-equalizer to improve my audio output.
If I only use my laptop with its own loudspeakers I don't have any problems, the equalizer adjusts the sound and sends it to the loudspeakers.

Now I want to send my audio to extern loudspeakers via a hdmi. But my ubuntu does not recognize them and plays audio via my laptop again.
If I open PulseAudio Volume Control I can change the output for each running program from *LADSPA Plugin Multiband EQ on Build-In Audio Analog Stereo* to *Built-In Audio* what solves the problem, but I don't want to do that every time, and I would like to use the EQ for the hdmi output, too.

Additionally, I could select *Built-In Audio Digital Stereo(HDMI)* in the PulseAudio Volume Control, but than there is no sound at all.